# How can I check if a string is available in a table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, string

[Here's the table (tblemployees)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZWZD.jpg)
How can I convert my code that used text files to a code that will use database (tables).

```
int intcurrentLine = -1;
String[] strLineSplit = (sb.toString()).split("\\r?\\n"); // converts sb to string then splits it by line
int intNumElements = strLineSplit.length; // number of elements
while (intcurrentLine != (intNumElements - 1)) {
    intcurrentLine++;
    String[] strWords = (strLineSplit[intcurrentLine]).split(" ", 2); // splits the current line by the first instance(space)
    if (strEmpID.equals(strWords[0])) { // checks if the employee ID is available
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + strWords[1] + ", you have successfully logged in.");
        strCheck = 1; // to confirm and go to time in and out process
        break;
    }
    if ((intcurrentLine + 1) == intNumElements) { // condition to state that ID cant be found from the employee list
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such employee, please check the ID No. that you entered.");
    }
}
```

Now I would like to search a column if it contains an Employee number. How do I put it to a condition, I've been searching but unable to find a clear answer. They only put how to search like this

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT * from messages WHERE EmpIDNo = 'COMSCI0001'";
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(queryCheck);
```

then I'm lost, how to make a condition where if the employee no. doesn't exists something would happen else something would happen. I'm just confuse how to make a condition for that.

Comment: One way would be checking how many record the result has. Another would be to count in the query directly and check that count: `SELECT count(*) as emp_cnt from messages WHERE EmpIDNo = 'COMSCI0001'`

Comment: use `res.next()` method

Comment: Edit your question and show the table structure you are intending to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE EmpIDNo = 'COMSCI0001' LIMIT 1";
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(queryCheck);
boolean exists = res.next();
```

The `boolean` variable `exists` will indicate whether a matching record exists or not.

Notice that I added `LIMIT 1` at the end of the SQL as an optimization to avoid fetching more data than you really need.

Comment: It will ensure that at most 1 records are loaded from the database. It's MySQL specific, it might not work with other databases.